# Adding a Rewrite rule to my PHP code

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I could not find a satisfying answer nowhere, and i know very basics about Rewrite Rules, but just can't find a way to achieve that. I would like to clip a certain portion of my address:

```
/entry.php?id=howdy-world
```

so, I would like it to look like this:

```
/entry/howdy-world/
```

I know how to point to a default file, or Rewrite get values to become numbers after the trailing slash, but the portion to be trimmed is kind of in the middle. How to deal with that?

Comment: You must have not looked very hard. This is the basis of most beginning rewrite tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the basic syntax of how to forward from one url to another. The below has a few sections

- **([^/] +)**: This matches any character multiple times up to a slash. *ex: entry/howdy-world/*
- **$1**: This would take what was after `entry/` and append it to the required url. *ex: entry.php?id=howdy-world*

More information on rewriting can be found on the [Apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

---

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^entry/([^/]+)$ entry.php?id=$1 [L]

 # Variations of above rule depending on server setup
 # RewriteRule ^entry/(.+)$ /entry.php?id=$1 [L]
 # RewriteRule ^entry/(.+)$ http://www.example.com/entry.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok, so I've tried these many times, even while I was looking for it, the thing is it doesn't work. Don't know the exact reason but it just doesn't seem to change the URL, and the second thing is when I apply any of this, I get the referral error.